# cglib is causing a java.lang.VerifyError during query generation in Intuit Partner Platform Java SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, cglib

I can't figure out what is causing this error.

I am using Intuit's Java v3 SDK for QuickBooks Online (QBO), and I'm attempting to run a query for TimeActivity objects. To do this, I must generate a query entity.

My code fails on this line:

```
TimeActivity queryTimeActivity = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(TimeActivity.class);
```

The stack trace proceeds from that line as follows:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-4da1515b5814ac28(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:795)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:360)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at com.intuit.ipp.query.GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(GenerateQuery.java:56)
```

I should mention that this code is in a Google App Engine app. I did some Google searches for this error, and found that many people suggest removing the libraries "cglib" and "asm" from the build path. I could not find "cglib", but I tried removing "asm-4.0.jar", but Google App Engine complained when I tried that. More specifically, the app deployed, but the line in question never ran when I removed asm.jar.

Does anyone have any ideas? I can't get my code to proceed beyond the aforementioned line.

Comment: I am not familiar with Inuit's Java SDK. Is that a JDK? If so, why do you have to use their SDK? Why can't you just use a standard JDK?

Comment: No. That's not what it is. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

Comment: It's a library that facilitates calls to Intuit's QuickBooks Online API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the exception is thrown during a call of the static initializer (`<clinit>`) of cglib's `Enhancer` class. Cglib uses ASM internally and it seems as if you have mismatching versions of cglib and ASM on your classpath.

From the error, I assmue that Intuit is using cglib 2.2 which relies on ASM 3.1. In [this version](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#visit%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), the `ClassWriter` did not declare its methods as `final`. This changed in [ASM 4](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#visit%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) such that cglib cannot be loaded because it overrides these now `final` methods.

What you could do is either

1. Remove ASM 4 from the class path but add ASM 3. See the POM for the fact that cglib 2.2.2 requires [ASM 3.1.1](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/cglib/cglib/2.2.2).
2. Explictly add cglib 3.1 to the class path which works with ASM 4. This might however break the application using cglib.

Usually, libraries using ASM should pack the latter under a different package to avoid zhis problem as documented in ASM's [FAQ](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q15). It seems as if the authors of Intuit missed that.

Finally, note it mentions [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/cglib/cglib/2.2) that cglib 2.2 is only partially supported by GAE.

Comment: Thanks for the specifics. It seems as if the authors of Intuit missed a lot of things. I find the Intuit Partner Platform to be extremely buggy. Anyway, I circumvented the problem altogether by writing my own query strings without the aid of GenerateQuery.

Comment: You are welcome. If your problem is resolved, please consider marking an answer and upvote any answer you found helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it worked fine.

```
TimeActivity timeActivity = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(TimeActivity.class);
String query   = select($(timeActivity.getId()),$(timeActivity.getSyncToken())).generate();
System.out.println("Generated Query - " + query);
QueryResult queryResult = service.executeQuery(query);
```

Can you check if it is working in your local system.

Thanks

Comment: It does work fine on my local system. It breaks when I deploy it to Google App Engine.

Comment: I ended up writing my own query string manually, since the whole purpose of GenerateQuery is to compose a SQL string. It seemed like much less hassle to bypass the convoluted query string generator.

The problem remains undiagnosed, but circumvented anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As raphw explains above, option 2 fixed it for me.  In my case I was using another artifact that included ASM 4.  I added the following dependency to my POM file and I no longer get the error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```